# How to make netstat output's headings show properly in out-gridview?

Tags: powershell, powershell-cmdlet, windows-11, powershell-7.2

[image]

when I use:

```
netstat -f | out-gridview
```

in PowerShell 7.3, I get the window but it has only one column which is a string. I don't know why it's not properly creating a column for each of the headings like Proto, Local Address etc.
how can I fix this?

Comment: netstat output is a string - you should use the powershell equivalent to netstat: ```Get-NetTCPConnection | Out-GridView```

Comment: @Toni Thank you, but how can I then make `Get-NetTCPConnection` output show real time data like netstat does?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While commenter [Toni](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19895159/toni) makes a good point to use `Get-NetTCPConnection | Out-GridView` instead, this answer addresses the question as asked.

To be able to show output of `netstat` in grid view, we have to parse its *textual* output into *objects*.

Fortunately, all fields are separated by at least two space characters, so after replacing these with comma, we can simply use [`ConvertFrom-CSV`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-csv?view=powershell-7.2) (thanks to an idea of commenter [Doug Maurer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4085331/doug-maurer)).

```sh
netstat -f | 
    # Skip unwanted lines at the beginning
    Select-Object -skip 3 | 
    # Replace two or more white space characters by comma, except at start of line
    ForEach-Object { $_ -replace '(?<!^)\s{2,}', ',' } |
    # Convert into an object and add it to grid view
    ConvertFrom-Csv | Out-GridView
```

For a detailed explanation of the RegEx pattern used with the `-replace` operator, see this [RegEx101 demo page](https://regex101.com/r/pkhNij/1).

---

This is the code of my original answer, which is functionally equivalent. I'll keep it as an example of how choosing the right tool for the job can greatly simplify code.

```sh
$headers = @()

# Skip first 3 lines of output which we don't need
netstat -f | Select-Object -skip 3 | ForEach-Object {
   
    # Split each line into columns
    $columns = $_.Trim() -split '\s{2,}'
   
    if( -not $headers ) {
        # First line is the header row
        $headers = $columns
    }
    else {
        # Create an ordered hashtable
        $objectProperties = [ordered] @{}
        $i = 0
        # Loop over the columns and use the header columns as property names
        foreach( $key in $headers ) {
            $objectProperties[ $key ] = $columns[ $i++ ]
        }
        # Convert the hashtable into an object that can be shown by Out-GridView
        [PSCustomObject] $objectProperties
    }
} | Out-GridView
```

Comment: Really appreciate the answer, specially the comments in the code, very helpful!

Comment: `(netstat -f) -match '^\s' -replace '(?<!^)\s{2,}',',' | ConvertFrom-Csv`

Comment: @DougMaurer Great idea! I've added it to this answer in a slightly modified variant, so output can be seen immediately when produced by `netstat`.